# Can't seem to find .pyc files?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm just starting out in python programming and I've noticed after running my python script `python text.py` few times, there are no .pyc files created. I understand .pyc are only created if its imported but how does `text.py` still run from command line if there is no .pyc file?

Comment: `.pyc` files are not strictly necessary, they're only there to make it faster to run Python code. You can also run Python code without having `.pyc` files.

Comment: When a script is run directly, the bytecode is constructed in memory but never written out to a `.pyc` file.

Comment: @SimeonVisser how does python run .py code if its not into bytecode  ? The code needs to be understandable for python virtual machine. Thanks for the reply though

Comment: @Rickx: yes, Python will convert the `.py` code but it doesn't have to write it to a `.pyc` file - it can run it directly without saving it.

Answer (score 7):

To expand on Rufflewind's answer: the rationale for not writing a .pyc for start-up scripts is twofold.  First, when files are being developed, writing a .pyc file wastes startup time when the file will be ignored on the next run.  Second, if a script is large enough that compile speed is noticeable and might matter, stable code can and perhaps should be moved to an imported module.  Indeed, for production use, it is standard practice to reduce a startup script to two statements, an import and main() call, as in `idlelib.__main__`.

```
""
IDLE main entry point
Run IDLE as python -m idlelib
"""
import idlelib.PyShell
idlelib.PyShell.main()
```