# Python compile all files to another structure

Tags: python, compilation

I have a Python project with files in a directories structure and I would like to get all .pyc files to the same directories to deliver without sources.

I am trying to do this with `python -m compileall -d /tmp/new -b .` but all pyc files are created in their respective sources directories instead of /tmp/new/somedir/

Any ideas? Will i have to create a script to recreate this structure?

Comment: You can try to move the directory iteratively in os.walk()

Comment: why not remove all .py files with `find` afterwards

Comment: That is the idea of the script i mention in my question : )

Comment: Benjamin, see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471928/way-to-have-compiled-python-files-in-a-separate-folder (Way to have compiled python files in a separate folder? PEP-304)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look about distributing *.pyc files:

[What are the limitations of distributing .pyc files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368304/what-are-the-limitations-of-distributing-pyc-files)

I suggest you use Py2Exe or cx_Freeze:

- http://www.py2exe.org/
- https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/

Comment: Thanks for this answer but I do not want an executable, I want to use this project as a library.

Comment: I have never used "pyc" files in this way, and I think that it's not a good idea, but if you want to try to do that, you should try to create a __pycache__ directory where you have the source files.
Or you can check the documentation, I think that example can be useful: https://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html