# Generate python bytecode cache in a user controlled directory

Tags: python-3.x, caching, bytecode

Python 2 and 3 both generate bytecode in the same directory as, or `__pycache__` subdirectory of scripts that you run. One reason it sucks is because it dirties source trees that I would like to keep clean for various reasons *that I don't need to explain for this question* (please answer this question - not questions that you imagine I have!)

I know you can disable cache generation, but that is inefficient.

Is there a way to run Python (2 or 3) but tell it to store its cache in a completely separate cache directory? Either using an environment variable or a command line flag.

*This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611967/can-compiled-bytecode-files-pyc-get-generated-in-different-directory) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471928/way-to-have-compiled-python-files-in-a-separate-folder).*

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53367609/1882946

For Python <3.8, this isn't possible, but working since 3.8.